# Loading descriptor error in Eclipse Neon 3

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

*I found several questions in stackoverflow asking the same issue but none of them have a proper solution*

I have created a Demo dynamic project in Eclipse.Now it shows an error message

```
An internal error occurred during: "Loading descriptor for DemoServlet.".
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.IllegalValueException: Value '
Container
' is not legal. (platform:/resource/DemoServlet/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml, 15, 
14)
```

This error message is showing again and again after some interval, But i'm able to run the project correctly.The descriptor is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" 
 version="3.1">
 <display-name>DemoServlet</display-name>

 <resource-ref>

 <res-ref-name>
   jdbc/javaDB
 </res-ref-name>
 <res-type>
   javax.sql.DataSource
 </res-type>
 <res-auth>
    Container
 </res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
 <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>Login.html</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

How can an eliminate this error from eclipse?

Comment: It's possible that the Eclipse tools are being overly strict and not expecting *any* whitespace around the actual value in `res-auth`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me.Could you please put it as an answer so that i can accept that.it may very helpful for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that the Eclipse tools are being overly strict and not expecting *any* whitespace around the actual value in `res-auth`. Try changing it so that only the word "Container" is in between the start and end tag.